# How to remove unused module js call in angular9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image: I will hit learning-path module but another 4 modules call as below image(all-access-pass ,page not found..etc ).]

I am using a lazy load module. But hit learning-path module but another 4 modules call as above image(all-access-pass, page not found..etc ).

How to remove unused module js?
every time call all module js.
Thanks in advance.

**app.router.module.js**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/course-home/course-home.module').then(m => m.CourseHomeModule),  pathMatch: 'full'},

  {
    path: 'all-access-pass', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/all-access-pass/all-access-pass.module').then(m => m.AllAccessPassModule)
  },

  {
    path: 'checkout', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/checkout/checkout.module').then(m => m.CheckoutModule)
  },
{
   path: 'checkout/order-success/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/thank-you/thank-you.module').then(m => m.ThankYouModule)
},
// {
//    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('../login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
// },
{
   path: 'registration', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/registration/registration.module').then(m => m.RegistrationModule)
},
  { path: 'free-trial-create-order', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/free-trial-create-order/free-trial-create-order.module')
  .then(m => m.FreeTrialCreateOrderModule) },
// Free trail Checkout.
  { path: 'all-access-pass-checkout', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/free-trial-checkout/free-trial-checkout.module')
  .then(m => m.FreeTrialCheckoutModule) },

// Free trial ThankYou.
  {
    path: 'all-access-pass-checkout/order-success/:id', loadChildren: () =>
    import('./pages/free-trial-thank-you/free-trial-thank-you.module')
    .then(m => m.FreeTrialThankYouModule)
  },
  { path: '404', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.module').then(m => m.PageNotFoundModule) },
 
  { path: 'all-access-pass-checkout-new', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/free-trial-checkout-variation/free-trial-checkout-variation.module').then(m => m.FreeTrialCheckoutVariationModule) },

  { path: 'all-access-pass-checkout-new/order-success/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/free-trial-variation-thank-you/free-trial-variation-thank-you.module').then(m => m.FreeTrialVariationThankYouModule) },
},

  { path: '**', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.module').then(m => m.PageNotFoundModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: it shouldnt load other lazy-loading modules actually, are you sure you didn't import them in other places?

Comment: created one shared module. that module use all over the project and imports in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you refer this:**

> Automatically Remove All Unused Imports in a TypeScript Project

https://wesleygrimes.com/angular/2019/02/14/how-to-use-tslint-to-autoremove-all-unused-imports-in-a-typescript-project.html